# Multiple logical comparisons on a single line for an if statement

Tags: python

I want to do multiple comparisons for a logical condition in python but I am not sure of the right way round for the `and` and `or`. I have 2 statements.

Statement 1:

```
#if PAB is more than BAC and either PAB is less than PAC or PAC is more than BAC
if PAB > BAC and PAB< PAC or PAB > BAC and PAC>BAC:
```

Statement 2:

```
#if PAB is more than BAC and PAC is less than PAB or if PAB is less than BAC and PAC is less than BAC
if PAB >BAC and  PAC<PAB or PAB<BAC and  PAC<BAC
```

Is or-ing the two ands the correct way to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: `PAB > BAC and PAB< PAC` is better written as `BAC < PAB < PAC`

Comment: `PAB`, `PAC` and `BAC` are angles of 3 triangles with common vertices. `PAB > BAC and PAB< PAC` can definitely be true.

Comment: @markmcmurray: I misread that as `a < b and b < a` - your variable names are too confusing!

Comment: @Eric The variable names aren't confusing. A, B and C are points on a triangle, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Eric They're not confusing in the context of how I am using them with triangles where the vertices are single letters (eg A,B,C,P)

Comment: By confusing, I meant "easy to misread". You're correct, those are completely appropriate names.

Comment: Sorry, I probably sounded a little rude in that previous comment, I was just stating that even though they mightn't be the clearest here, this is the clearest way to do them in the context of my code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looking at statement 1, I'm assuming you mean:

```
if (PAB > BAC and PAB< PAC) or (PAB > BAC and PAC>BAC):
```

In which case, I'd probably write it like this (using *chained comparisons*, docs: [python2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)):

```
if (BAC < PAB < PAC) or min(PAB,PAC)>BAC:
```

You can use an analogous form for statement 2.

Having said that, I cannot make your comments in the question's code match up with my interpretation of your conditionals, so it's plausible I don't understand your requirement.