# Multiple comparison operators in single statement (chaining comparison operators)

Tags: python

Does this do what I think it does?

```
assert 1 < 2 < 3
```

I couldn't find any reference to this in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) but I saw it in a high rep [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424639/4653485).

It seems to work but it could be luck, like the leftmost resolves to `True`, then `True` is used in the other.

I did a few tests and it always work as expected, but I'd like to find a source (a doc) stating explicitly that it is intended.

```
>>> 1<2<3<4<5
True
>>> 1<2<7<4<5
False
>>> 1<2<3>2<5
True
```

This rules out the "leftmost first" hypothesis:

```
>>> 1<3<2
False
>>> (1<3)<2
True
```

Comment: The docs you link reference it explicitly

Comment: @PeterWood. You're right. I somehow missed it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I was just about to make the same question. I wasn't finding information about it anywhere!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is documented in detail in the [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) chapter of the documentation:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
> to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, ..., *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, ..., *opN*
> are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent
> to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is
> evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that `a op1 b op2 c` doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between *a*
> and *c*, so that, e.g., `x < y > z` is perfectly legal (though perhaps not
> pretty).

Comment: Thanks. "Chaining" is the search keyword I was missing. I couldn't find anything relevant searching for "multiple".

Comment: That's exactly the [same text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) (albeit a different part of the documentation) that the OP linked.

Comment: @Peter: only the 1st paragraph ;)