# Python "in" and "==" confusion

Tags: python

```
print('a' in 'aa')
print('a' in 'aa' == True)
print(('a' in 'aa') == True)
print('a' in ('aa' == True))
```

The output is

```
True
False
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print('a' in ('aa' == True))
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

If line 2 is neither line 3 nor line 4, then what is it? How does it get False?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm finding it unusually difficult to find the canonical I'm thinking of. It's due to chaining but I can't find the link :/

Comment: That's the one you originally flagged with but I'm _sure_ there is a canonical. Where is it?! :P

Comment: @roganjosh  this here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python/6074117#6074117

Comment: @PatrickArtner Not me! I wondered where it went. I was searching for the main one to add to the dupe. EDIT: maybe I'm thinking of some happy mashup of the two into a single question/answer

Comment: It is similar to 'a < b < c'.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it got hammered and they presumably decided to reverse that, but now it shows no close votes to me.

Comment: @PatrickArtner i saw timgeb as the second closer. It must be a hammer. I'm not sure how to view that history, though.

Comment: I hammered and then decided that hammer may have been premature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

```
print('a' in 'aa' == True)
```

is evaluated as

```
'a' in 'aa' and 'aa' == True
```

which is `False`.

See

```
print("a" in "aa" and "aa" == True)
```

==> `False`

The rest is trivial - it helps to keep [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in mind to figure them out.

---

Similar ones:

- [Multiple comparison operators in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677790/multiple-comparison-operators-in-single-statement)
- [Why does the expression 0 < 0 == 0 return False in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python/6074117#6074117)

with different statements. I flagged for dupe but the UI is wonky - I answered non the less to explain why *yours* exactly printed what it did.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 : it's simple the answers is `True`.

```
print('a' in 'aa')
```

Case 2 : This operation is evaluated as `'a' in 'aa' and 'aa' == True`, so obviously it will return false.

```
print('a' in 'aa' == True)
```

Case 3: Now because we have `()` enclosing `('a' in 'aa')` and the precedence of `()` is highest among all so first `'a' in 'aa'` is evaluated as `True` and then `True == True`

```
print(('a' in 'aa') == True)
```

Case 4 : Same as above because of precedence of `()`, its evaluated as `'aa' == True`, which will result in error as it tries to apply `in` on a non iterable that is bool value.

```
print('a' in ('aa' == True))
```

Comment: comparing a string with a bool is perfectly fine - the error is trying to use `in` on a non iterable bool type ...

Comment: Comparing a string to a Boolean does not throw an error.