# Python dual condition in if statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Im trying to satisfy 2 conditions in the if statement with the word AND but it does not seem to be working. is there something wrong? Im basically trying to print the largest of e1,e2 and e3.

```
    if e1 > e2 AND e3:
          then print elapsed 1
    elif:
          e2>e3
          then print e2
    else:
          print e3
```

Comment: Firstly, it's `and` and not `AND`

Comment: Most of that isn't even nearly Python syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424484/multiple-logical-comparisons-on-a-single-line-for-an-if-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1 - duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to say

```
if e1 > e2 and e1 > e3:
    print(e1)
elif e2 > e3:
    print(e2)
else:
    print(e3)
```

then it will work.

Comment: It's `and` and not `AND`

Comment: yes, this is correct its lowercase and i changed it. but the function is still not working.

Comment: @analog_kid: What's the error/message/output you are getting? What's your input?

Comment: the above solution appears to be working now. thank you very much!